# How to get list of DNS servers for system resolver

Tags: go

In Ruby I can get the list of DNS servers like this:

```
require 'resolv'
Resolv::DNS::Config.default_config_hash[:nameserver]
```

How to do the same in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Resolver type](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Resolver) in the `net` package lets you resolve DNS names but it doesn't seem to export the DNS servers it uses.

[Ruby parses `/etc/resolv.conf`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/resolv.rb#L983) so I guess you'll have to do that yourself or see if you can find a package that does it for you.

*Update: I made [a small library](https://github.com/fiskeben/resolv) to do sort of the same as Ruby's DNS class. Hope it helps.*